# Use local state for forms when data is in redux

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-redux

> Use React for ephemeral state that doesn’t matter to the app globally
>   and doesn’t mutate in complex ways. For example, a toggle in some UI
>   element, a form input state. Use Redux for state that matters globally
>   or is mutated in complex ways. For example, cached users, or a post
>   draft.

My redux state is only representative of what has been saved to my backend database.

For my use case there is no need for any other part of the application to know about a record in an adding/editing state..

However, all my communication with my API is done through redux-thunks. I have found, getting data from redux into local state for editing is tricky.

The pattern I was trying to use:

```
const Container = () => {
    // use redux thunk to fetch from API
    useEffect(() => {
      dispatch(fetchThing(id));
    }, [dispatch, id]);

    // get from redux store
    const reduxThing = useSelector(getThing);

    const save = thing => {
      dispatch(saveThing(thing));
    };

    return (
      {!fetching && 
       <ThingForm 
        defaults={reduxThing} 
        submit={save}
      />}
    );
};

const ThingForm = ({defaults, submit}) => {
    const [values, setValues] = useState({ propA: '', propB: '', ...defaults});
    const handleChange = { /*standard handleChange code here*/ };

    return (
        <form onSubmit={() => submit(values)}>
          <input type="text" name="propA" value={values.propA} onChange={handleChange} />
          <input type="text" name="propB" value={values.propB} onChange={handleChange} />
        </form>
    );
};
```

How I understand it, ThingForm is unmounted/mounted based upon "fetching."  However, it is a race condition whether or not the defaults get populated. Sometimes they do, sometimes they don't.

So obviously this isn't a great pattern.

Is there an established pattern for moving data into local state from redux for editing in a form?

Or should I just put my form data into redux? (I don't know if this would be any easier).

---

EDIT: I think this is essentially what I am fighting: https://reactjs.org/blog/2018/06/07/you-probably-dont-need-derived-state.html 
But no recommendation really clearly fits.  I am strictly using hooks. I could overwrite with useEffect on prop change, but seems kind of messy.

Comment: If/when your forms get more complex you might give [Formik](https://jaredpalmer.com/formik/docs/overview) a whirl. The developer points out a similar quote from Dan Abramov: "form state is inherently ephemeral and local, so tracking it in Redux (or any kind of Flux library) is unnecessary". It's a cracking lightweight library.

Comment: What exactly do you found tricky ? It would be very helpful if you reproduce the problem in a https://codesandbox.io

Comment: @MohamedRamrami - I'll try to do that. It's tricky because conditionally rendering leads to a race condition. And if I don't conditionally render the form state is set to defaults before the data comes back from the server and is never set.

Comment: @Andy I think I might have the same troubles with Formik moving redux data into local state

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**EDIT:**

```
const Container = () => {
    // use redux thunk to fetch from API
    useEffect(() => {
      dispatch(fetchThing(id));
    }, [dispatch, id]);

    // get from redux store
    const reduxThing = useSelector(getThing);

    const save = thing => {
      dispatch(saveThing(thing));
    };

    return (
      {!fetching && 
       <ThingForm 
        defaults={reduxThing} 
        submit={save}
      />}
    );
};

const ThingForm = ({defaults, submit}) => {
    const [values, setValues] = useState({ propA: '', propB: '', ...defaults});
    const handleChange = { /*standard handleChange code here*/ };


   useEffect(() => {
     setValues({...values, ...defaults})
   }, [defaults]);

    const submitValues = (e) => {
      e.preventDefault();
      submit(values)
    }

    return (
        <form onSubmit={submitValues}>
          <input type="text" name="propA" value={values.propA} onChange={handleChange} />
          <input type="text" name="propB" value={values.propB} onChange={handleChange} />
        </form>
    );
};
```

---

What you are doing is the right way, there's no reason why you should put the form data in the redux store. Like you said, "there is no need for any other part of the application to know about a record in an adding/editing state"
And that's correct.

The only problem you have is here:

```
{!fetching && 
       <ThingForm 
        defaults={reduxThing} 
        submit={save}
      />}
```

Assuming `fetching` is true on every dispatch:

Instead of trying to hide the component (unmounting essentially), you should maybe use a spinner that overlays the page?

I don't know the rest of your code to comment on a better approach.

You also don't have to add dispatch to the dependency array

```
useEffect(() => {
      dispatch(fetchThing(id));
    }, [id]);
```

From the react docs:

> React guarantees that dispatch function identity is stable and won’t change on re-renders. This is why it’s safe to omit from the useEffect or useCallback dependency list.

Comment: I did that originally, however it seems 1. my defaults are set in the forms state 2. then i get the data from redux selector, and the form state is never updated.

Comment: For the dispatch, I use ceate-react-app which seems to come with the eslint rule react-hooks/exhausive-deps, and I have prettier set up to fix my lint errors on save, so it throws dispatch in there for me, I don't think it hurts does it?

Comment: Oh, so you actually want it to get re-rendered? And you need it to re-render on change in the id?

Comment: Nah, it doesn't hurt. You can leave it for the lint error I guess.

Comment: no I just did that to try to get the data returned from the server to populate. If I don't conditionally render, the defaults are set into state and never updated when the data comes back.

Comment: Oh I see where your issue is. I'll update the answer in a minute.

Comment: Updated. Check it out. And you an remove the conditional check `fetching`

Comment: Thanks.  Yes, I see you note the issue, but how do I fix? I'm afraid updating them in useEffect may lead to a render loop and is kind of messy

Comment: But the data is never properly initialized. Say data comes back `thing: { propA: 'hello', propB: 'World'}`.  My form is still showing blanks.

Comment: I added an example. Check it out. The answer is correct.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/199330/discussion-between-user210757-and-paruchuri-p).

Comment: This is the route I will probably go, my only holdup is this may be an anti-pattern and I worry it's going to bite me (https://reactjs.org/blog/2018/06/07/you-probably-dont-need-derived-state.html)